# Recreate dataframe to use for-loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am learning student and doing capstone work.
This is part of my code.

```
   for(i in divvy_trips){
       trip<-get(i)
       if ("starttime" %in% names(trip)){
            trip$starttime <- as.character(trip$starttime)
            trip$stoptime <- as.character(trip$stoptime)
       get(i) <- trip
```

In this code, I want use in divvy_trips that contain data frames and fix some column as character and recreate dataframe as same name. but

get(i) <- trip

deosn't work. so I need some help to work this objective but another method.

Comment: (1) What exact structure is `divvy_trips`? A list of data.frames? (2) What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to change every column `starttime`/`stoptime` in every data.frame of `divvy_trips` into character? (3) Please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It is not intended as a solution but as a tip (as I cannot really understand what you're trying to achieve): your last line should be `assign(i, trip)` (or simething similar) instead of `get(i) <-  trip`.

Comment: oh, I know assign as only vector like 'trip <- c(1,2,3) ' when assign(i,trip), trip is do else if trip is data frame?

Answer (score 0):

If your data structure is indeed a list of data.frames like this

```r
trip_1 <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
trip_2 <- data.frame(a = 91:100, starttime = 1:10, stoptime = 11:20)

divvy_trip <- list(trip_1 = trip_1, trip_2 = trip_2)
```

You could use `lapply` to solve your problem:

```r
divvy_trip <- lapply(divvy_trip, 
                     function(dat) {
                       if ("starttime" %in% names(dat)) {
                         dat$starttime <- as.character(dat$starttime)
                         dat$stoptime <- as.character(dat$stoptime) 
                         }
                       dat
                       }
                     )
```

This changes the `starttime` and `stoptime` column of the data.frame `trip_2` into character:

```r
class(divvy_trip[["trip_2"]][["starttime"]])
#> [1] "character"
```